# Hugo - MD file in main menu gives 404

Tags: hugo

I have a hugo site with an about page inside the `repo_name/themes/theme_name/content/file.md`
[image]

In my `config.toml` file I added the lines.

```
  [[menu.main]]
    identifier = "about"
    name       = "about"
    url        = "/about/"
    weight     = 2
```

But when I hit the URL `localhost:1313/about/` its giving 404.

Comment: Shouldn't that about.md be in your content folder - not your themes content folder... I.e. move it up...

Comment: I tried both `/repo_name/contents/pages/about.md` and `themes/contents/pages/about.md` but no luck

Comment: /repo_name/contents/pages/about.md  
change to:
/repo_name/content/about.md

Comment: Unless you want this to be /pages/about/ but then change your link to /pages/about/

Comment: Tried, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Your about.md file can be seen as a resource instead of a page. Adding an _index.md file to your content folder (the home page) will fix this. Additionally I would think that the about page is not part of the theme, but part of your repo. Not sure if this causes the 404, but I think the page belongs here:

```
/repo_name/content/about.md
```